# How do I create movable labels on a UIView?

Tags: uiview, uikit, touchesmoved

I am trying to create four touchable and movable labels on a `UIView`.

When I touch a `ifAnimaPart01` somehow they are all gathered in one location and I can not touch or move the other labels.

Does anyone know why my four labels are acting this way?

I added another 4 labels to display the x and y coordinates for debugging.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{   


UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if ([touch view] == ifAnimPart01){
        ifAnimPart01.center = location;
    }   
    else if ([touch view] == ifAnimPart02){
        ifAnimPart02.center= location;
    }   
    else if ([touch view] == ifAnimPart03){
        ifAnimPart03.center= location;
    }
    else if ([touch view] == ifAnimPart04){
        ifAnimPart04.center= location;
    }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint1 = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    xCoordLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line OneX = %f", startPoint1.x];
    yCoordLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line OneY = %f", startPoint1.y];
    ifAnimPart01.center = CGPointMake(startPoint1.x, startPoint1.y);

    startPoint2 = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    xCoordLabel2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line TwoX = %f", startPoint2.x];
    yCoordLabel2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line TwoY = %f", startPoint2.y];
    ifAnimPart02.center = CGPointMake(startPoint2.x, startPoint2.y);

    startPoint3 = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    xCoordLabel3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line ThreeX = %f", startPoint3.x];
    yCoordLabel3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line ThreeY = %f", startPoint3.y];
    ifAnimPart03.center = CGPointMake(startPoint3.x, startPoint3.y);

    startPoint4 = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    xCoordLabel4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line FourX = %f", startPoint4.x];
    yCoordLabel4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line FourY = %f", startPoint4.y];
    ifAnimPart04.center = CGPointMake(startPoint4.x, startPoint4.y);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}
```

Comment: Omg ;((  Where can I set that? I did not know that?

Comment: Just click on the check box outline to the left of the answer. Here is the relevant section of the FAQ: [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).